# Iptables logging in Ubuntu

Tags: iptables, logging

I have set up Cowrie (2222) and SSH (2233) on a Ubuntu server, to block all traffic except Cowrie and SSH, I have run the following commands:

```shell
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2233 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Now I need to log all SSH, Honeypot and Cowrie traffic with the following prefix

`"SSH_Traffic, Honeypot_Traffic, Blocked_Traffic".`

I would appreciate if someone could help with this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked for will flood your log files, use with caution.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j LOG --log-prefix "Cowrie_Traffic:" --log-level info
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2223 -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH_Traffic:" --log-level info
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2233 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Blocked_Traffic:" --log-level info
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Honeypot_Traffic you did not tell us about.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I will give it a go